# How to set delete icon instead of Delete text for editing table view mode in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I have added a table view using XIB, by default i am getting Delete text after swiping on my custom table view cell, that text title we can change using method. I don't want to use "SWTableViewCell" source code. how can i replace Delete title from any icon image as i have mention in below image :

[image]

I have tried with custom editingAccessoryView.

here is the code (in table cellForRowAtIndexPath):

```
   UIView *editingCategoryAccessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,80)];
    editingCategoryAccessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_highlighted.png"]];

    UIButton *deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    deleteButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString1 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"DELETE"];

    [attributedString1 addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName
                             value:@(1.5)
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [@"DELETE" length])];

    deleteButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    UIColor *btnTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // Set up attributes
    NSDictionary *btnAttrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [UIFont fontWithName:@"Cabin-Bold" size:17.0f], NSFontAttributeName,
                              btnTextColor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                              nil, NSKernAttributeName, nil];

    [attributedString1 setAttributes:btnAttrs
                            range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString1.length)];

    [attributedString1 addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName
                              value:@(1.5)
                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [@"DELETE" length])];

    [deleteButton setAttributedTitle:attributedString1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    [deleteButton setFrame:cell.frame];
    [deleteButton setTag:indexPath.row];
    [deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(removeCategoryClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

   // UIImageView

    UIImageView *ivDeleteIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(21, 31, 13, 15)];
    ivDeleteIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Delete-White.png"];
    ivDeleteIcon.highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Delete-Grey.png"];
    [editingCategoryAccessoryView addSubview:ivDeleteIcon];
    [editingCategoryAccessoryView addSubview:deleteButton];

    cell.editingAccessoryView = editingCategoryAccessoryView;


// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES; //YES here makes a red delete button appear when I swipe
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (editing)
        editingFromEditButton = YES;
    [super setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated];
    editingFromEditButton = NO;
    // Other code you may want at this point...
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingFromEditButton){
        //editCell = YES;
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }
    // Otherwise, we are at swipe to delete
    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setEditing:YES animated:YES];

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
         [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}
```

Above code is working fine, but only it's not getting dismissed properly.
Please help me to achieve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible by custom editingAccessoryView, but i have used SWTableViewCell. First you need to add SWTableViewCell classes in your app. here is my code:

custom table view cell .h file (create a custom table view cell with super class "SWTableViewCell") as below :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SWTableViewCell.h"

@interface UpdateTableCell : SWTableViewCell {

}

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UILabel *lblTitle;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UILabel *lblViewMore;

@end
```

custom table view cell .m file :

```
#import "UpdateTableCell.h"

@implementation UpdateTableCell

@synthesize lblTitle, lblViewMore;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code.
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state.
}

@end
```

In your View Controller.h file :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SWTableViewCell.h"

@interface MyBriefcaseViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, SWTableViewCellDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *tblBriefcase;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arrayBriefcase;

@end
```

View Controller.m file :

```
#import "MyBriefcaseViewController.h"
#import "UpdateTableCell.h"
#import "SWTableViewCell.h"

@implementation MyBriefcaseViewController

-(UpdateTableCell *)getNewCell
{
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UpdateTableCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    UpdateTableCell *cell;
    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UpdateTableCell class]])
        {
            cell= (UpdateTableCell *)currentObject;
            return cell;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    UpdateTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [self getNewCell];
    }

    //optionally specify a width that each set of utility buttons will share
    [cell setRightUtilityButtons:[self rightButtons] WithButtonWidth:85.0f];
    cell.delegate = self;

    //do something here..

    return cell;
}

- (NSArray *)rightButtons  
{
    NSMutableArray *rightUtilityButtons = [NSMutableArray new];

    [rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:[UIColor redColor] normalIcon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Delete-White.png"] selectedIcon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Delete-Grey.png"]];// here you can change delete image icon and background color of editing view as per your requirement

    return rightUtilityButtons;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //Set background color of cell here if you don't want default white
}

#pragma mark - SWTableViewDelegate

- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell scrollingToState:(SWCellState)state
{
    switch (state) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"utility buttons closed");
            break;
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"left utility buttons open");
            break;
        case 2:
            NSLog(@"right utility buttons open");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    // Delete button was pressed
    NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [tblBriefcase indexPathForCell:cell];

    // do something here as per your requirement
}

- (BOOL)swipeableTableViewCellShouldHideUtilityButtonsOnSwipe:(SWTableViewCell *)cell
{
    //allow just one cell's utility button to be open at once
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell canSwipeToState:(SWCellState)state
{
    return YES;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (!tableView.isEditing) {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }

   //do something here...

}
```

I have attached all my required code here in my answer to achieve this. Surely, it will work. Thanks to all!!

happy coding.. :)

Comment: above code will only work for iOS7, not in iOS6. I have tested, please let me know in case of any problem. Thanks!